# How to Compare Two Text Files within Pandas Python and Have the Output Highlighted in A Different Excel or Text File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have looked through multiple ways in how to compare the two gfiles. 
One of the ways I have looked and dicovered to compare the two files was to use the Pandas Module. The other way in which I discovered was to use the Numpy module within Python, I am also using various other modules to help me work with Excel sheets. The main thing is I have an ACII text file that I need to compare with another file. Both files are the same size and I have even included a check to see if the files are the same size, but I think there is something wrong with conditional statements that check the overall size of the two files. So basically I need some advice here on how to compare the two files.

The text file uses UTF-Encoding 8.
The information will look like this:

```
StudentID,Code,Date,FirstName,LastName,GradeLevel,CampusID
000001,R,mm/dd/yyyy/,JOHN,SMITH,01,00001
```

The header is not seen within the original file I have to compare. 
Original File Header:

```
StudentID,Code,Date,FirstName,LastName,GradeLevel,CampusID
```

The file I pull out from our SIS database, has headers that match

```
StudentID,Code,Date,FirstName,LastName,GradeLevel,CampusID
```

But some of the formatting is a little different. 
For example the data is not `mm/dd/yyyy` and the CampusID is only `###`
The documentation that I have looked at to help me has shown the following:

- [Using Pandas to between Two Dataframes](https://kanoki.org/2019/07/04/pandas-difference-between-two-dataframes/)
- [Using Pandas to Compare Two Excel Files](https://kanoki.org/2019/02/26/compare-two-excel-files-for-difference-using-python/)
- [Working with Missing Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)
- [Pandas Cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html)

Now I have been able to print out data in a concatenated data frame, but I have not really been able to run comparisons yet and highlight the differences between the two files be it text or excel files. I was curious if anyone could point me in a direction or a better direction is they know how to compare files. 
I am using the following code right now and it is at least printing the data frames, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything other than printing them as a pandas data frame.

```
#!/bin/python 
# ===========================================================
# Created By: Richard Barrett
# Organization: DVISD
# DepartmenT: Data Services
# Purpose: Dynamic Excel Diff Comparison Report
# Date: 02/28/2020
# ===========================================================

import getpass
import json
import logging
import numpy as np 
import os 
import pandas as pd
import platform  
import shutil 
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import unittest
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date

# System Variables
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
node = platform.node()
system = platform.system()
username = getpass.getuser()
version = platform.version()
working_directory = os.getcwd()
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# File Variables on Relative Path within CWD
file_1 = "ExportPOSStudents.xlsx"
file_2 = "ExportNutrikidsSkywardCompare.xlsx"

# Column Variables to Compare
e_code = "Eligibility Code"
e_date = "Effective Date"
f_name = "First Name"
l_name = "Last Name"

# Logging Variables 

# Ensure that the Files Exist
if os.path.exists(file_1) and os.path.exists(file_2):
    print("The Files Exist.")
else:
    print("One of the files might not exist.")

# Create Dataframes
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_2)

print(df1)
print(df2)

# Check to See if Files are Same Size
df1.equals(df2)
if print(df1.equals(df2)) is False:
    print("Dataframes are not the same size.")
else:
    print("Dataframes are the same size.")

df1[e_date].equals(df2[e_date])
if print(df1[e_date].equals(df2[e_date])) is False:
    print("The Entries are not the same within column for e_date.")
else:
    print("The Entries are the same within the columns for e_date.")

#comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
#print(comparison_values)
#if df2.equals(df1) == False:
#    print("Datframes are not of the the same size.")
#else df2.equals(df1) == True: 
#    print("Dataframes are of the same size.")

# If Files are Not Same Size Check Indexes and Column Names and Format

# Check Indexes and Size 

# Compare Dataframe Values
#if comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
#    print(comparison_values)
#else:
#    print("Cannot compare Dataframes.")

# Get-Index of Cell with Parameter == False
#rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

# Iterate over Cells and Update (df1) value to display changed value in second dataframe (df2)
#for item in zip(rows,cols):
#    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.i

# Export to Excel after df1(Old Value) --> df2(New Value)
#df1.to_excel('./excel_diff.xlsx',index=False,header=True)
```

You can see the main code and process here that I am trying to achieve: [Link to Code and Process](https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/tree/master/Python/Analyses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compare two excel sheets using the following:
Afterwards, you will have a new spreadsheet with three workbooks in it.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


def excel_diff(path_OLD, path_NEW, index_col):

    df_OLD = pd.read_excel(path_OLD, index_col=index_col).fillna(0)
    df_NEW = pd.read_excel(path_NEW, index_col=index_col).fillna(0)

    # Perform Diff
    dfDiff = df_NEW.copy()
    droppedRows = []
    newRows = []

    cols_OLD = df_OLD.columns
    cols_NEW = df_NEW.columns
    sharedCols = list(set(cols_OLD).intersection(cols_NEW))

    for row in dfDiff.index:
        if (row in df_OLD.index) and (row in df_NEW.index):
            for col in sharedCols:
                value_OLD = df_OLD.loc[row,col]
                value_NEW = df_NEW.loc[row,col]
                if value_OLD==value_NEW:
                    dfDiff.loc[row,col] = df_NEW.loc[row,col]
                else:
                    dfDiff.loc[row,col] = ('{}→{}').format(value_OLD,value_NEW)
        else:
            newRows.append(row)

    for row in df_OLD.index:
        if row not in df_NEW.index:
            droppedRows.append(row)
            dfDiff = dfDiff.append(df_OLD.loc[row,:])

    dfDiff = dfDiff.sort_index().fillna('')
    print(dfDiff)
    print('\nNew Rows:     {}'.format(newRows))
    print('Dropped Rows: {}'.format(droppedRows))

    # Save output and format
    fname = '{} vs {}.xlsx'.format(path_OLD.stem,path_NEW.stem)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter')

    dfDiff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DIFF', index=True)
    df_NEW.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=path_NEW.stem, index=True)
    df_OLD.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=path_OLD.stem, index=True)

    # get xlsxwriter objects
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['DIFF']
    worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)
    worksheet.set_default_row(15)

    # define formats
    date_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd'})
    center_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center'})
    number_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
    cur_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '$#,##0.00'})
    perc_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'num_format': '0%'})
    grey_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#E0E0E0'})
    highlight_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#FF0000', 'bg_color':'#B1B3B3'})
    new_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#32CD32','bold':True})

    # set format over range
    ## highlight changed cells
    worksheet.conditional_format('A1:ZZ1000', {'type': 'text',
                                            'criteria': 'containing',
                                            'value':'→',
                                            'format': highlight_fmt})

    # highlight new/changed rows
    for row in range(dfDiff.shape[0]):
        if row+1 in newRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, new_fmt)
        if row+1 in droppedRows:
            worksheet.set_row(row+1, 15, grey_fmt)

    # save
    writer.save()
    print('\nDone.\n')


def main():
    path_OLD = Path('v1.xlsx')
    path_NEW = Path('v2.xlsx')

    # get index col from data
    df = pd.read_excel(path_NEW)
    index_col = df.columns[0]
    print('\nIndex column: {}\n'.format(index_col))

    excel_diff(path_OLD, path_NEW, index_col)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You will have to work with the highlighting in the book as I am still having an issue with it. NOTE THIS ANSWER WORKS ONLY WITH EXCEL SPREADSHEETS